Logic of scales of measurement (Nominal, ordinal, etc.) when transforming variables
Scales of measurement often discussed as:

Nominal: Qualitative category with no order
Ordinal: Order but no meaningful distance between values
Interval: Order and meaningful distance between values
Ratio: Order and meaningful distance and true zero

I was curious about the logic of scale of measurement when a transformation is done on the original variable.
For example

Income (Ratio) -> natural logarithm -> Log(Income) ratio? no true zero, the value of distance changes
Height (Ratio) -> standardize to mean of zero and sd of 1 -> Z score Height (interval?) Zero represents the mean.

Do we apply the logic of the scales of measurement on the transformed variable and possibly recategorize when relevant?

Because the original "logic" is really based on a group of transformations, and the same group acts albeit it in an algebraically different way on one-to-one transformations of values, the scale of measurement is (from this perspective) not changed at all under a transformation: you just have to pay attention to how that transformation is carried out.  (You conjugate the group action by the transformation: that is, untransform the values, apply the group action, and re-transform.) This perspective unifies the concepts of interval and ratio measurement scales, btw.

In your first example (log(income)), you went from ratio to interval-scale; because now "0" no longer corresponds to "absence of income" (but to income of 1). This is why one uses log(1+x); now this remains ratio-scale. (because 0 is still absence of income).  In your 2nd example, standardizing to get $\sigma=1$ keeps it ratio-scale, but shifting the mean to 0 makes it interval. Now, I can not think of a statistical test which would be admissible only for ratio-scale, and not interval? (?odds ratio?). Maybe others have examples?

@jginestet Even though it keeps the same 0 point, having a zero is not sufficient for it to be ratio; log(1+Y) does NOT have the property that "2" is "twice as much" as "1" (etc) that's essential to a ratio scale. e.g. if I consider a mass of 10kg vs one of 5kg, the second is twice the first, but if I add one and take logs, the value of ~1.338 for their ratio doesn't represent "1.338 times as much"

@Glen, indeed... But then what scale is it? Not interval (the distances are not the same between 1 and 2 and 2 and 3). But it is more than ordinal? (we can interpret the differences, as in fact ratios). And it does not seem to prevent many from log transforming data (such as income...), because of "non normality", and happily applying all sorts of statiscal tests. So ?


My understanding of Stevens' paper is that he would have argued that the transformation you mentioned is not permissible (his language is fairly prescriptive). 2. Stevens' typology fails to adequately  describe all variables you might encounter, and at the least does not constitute a suitable guide to analysis in a statistically useful sense. Velleman & Wilkinson point out that the type actually depends on how you treat the variable (they give an example where the same variable could arguably be any of Stevens' types depending on how you use it). Note the existence of other typologies...ctd


ctd... (e.g. Mosteller & Tukey is considerably more comprehensive and more useful in terms of statistical issues, though arguably there are some 'type'-related aspects not addressed there). Some of these issues are discussed in a number of answers on site.

@Glen_b, thanks for expanding. I would tend to be as "prescriptive" and "formal" (rigid?) as Stevens (I had read his paper), and would say that a log transform is not "permissible", unless the log is the natural measure of the phenomenon, Taking the log of income (as is often done because it is "not normal" should not be "permissible"  (unless I can buy a car for the log of its sticker price...). But, if dealing with Beer-Lambert's law, dealing with absorption of energy (light, but also ultrasound, gamma rays, etc.) in a medium, which is exponential, then taking the log is natural ...ctd

...ctd This gives you a quantity proportional to the depth in the medium, which is a "natural" physical quantity. I could perform all the statistical tests I need in this domain, and make all the inferences I care to, in terms of the log domain (depth/distance).  Now, if I want to back-transform my results, that is a whole new story (and I should have my old math teacher slap my fingers with his ruler).

Many commentators refer or allude to Stevens' first paper in Science 1946, whereas in later papers and until his  posthumous book Psychophysics in 1975 he continued to make extra comments and minor revisions.

The NOIR scheme has some merit but is in my view seriously incomplete; frequently irrelevant or dubious in principle, practice or both; and often oversold. For example, it really is true that ratios of weights make sense, but ratios of Fahrenheit or Celsius temperatures do not. Conversely, despite what many people say, means of ordinal variables are often used and often quite useful, while a scale being interval or ratio is no guarantee of the utility of means, however such scales are touted as being their natural habitat.
Your questions expose some of the limitations of the ideas as often explained.

Once you take logarithms of positive variables, it is no longer ratios that make sense but differences. That's much of the point: ratios are mapped to differences. Zero isn't arbitrary for logarithms, as it's always the logarithm of 1 in any base. In short, the logarithm of a ratio variable is no longer a ratio variable, but that is not troubling.

Standardizing a positive variable in the sense of (value $-$ mean) / SD raises similar but not identical issues. Such a variable is no longer a ratio variable in the sense you've defined it, but that is not troubling.


The moral in that second case is that a linear transformation with a constant destroys the ratio properties. But is that a problem? A linear transformation preserves all the information in such a variable.
It's a social observation that this scheme seems much more widely discussed in some disciplines using statistics (dare I mention my impression that psychology, sociology and some branches of biology are prominent in this respect?) than in others.
Almost thirty years ago, David Hand and his discussants explored such questions from several angles in this key paper. It's not clear to me whether statistical science(s) are now any closer to a consensus on such matters.

I do not think that the OP was interested in rations of income, or height. He was indicating that Income is a ratio scale, and wondering whether log(Income) is still a ration scale? Same for height. Now, for log(), there is no longer a meaningful 0 (it no longer corresponds to "absence of income", whereas e.g. length of 0 is absence of length) One could argue that we now have an interval scale. Which is why one often uses (log(1+x); now we are still ratio-scale, because 0 corresponds to "absence of income" (as it should).

ration for ratio is an unfortunate typo; it needs a passing moderator to fix that.

@jginestet You raise several points, but none seem to undermine my answer.  In thinking and teaching about measurement scales I have found that "ratios make sense" is a good informal starting point for discussing ratio scales, but it is manifestly not a formal definition. The point to working with logarithm of income is mostly about changes in income being often multiplicative not additive and about the advantages of pulling in long tails; whether distributions are or are not normal or even lognormal is by comparison of secondary importance.

(ctd) log(1 + y) is a transformation I've used myself on the grounds that 0 is often a data value  in distributions that would benefit from logarithmic transformation. But I think it's more problematic and achieves less than you imply. For income in particular, whether 1 is 1 cent, 1 dollar, or whatever is a troubling detail. Like other commentators, I want to flag that scale of measurement and data transformation are only loosely linked.
